# Is there a way to produce multiple x-y scatterplots at once based on grouping value, ordered by a third variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multi-level data. The group level is individual persons, which are designated by id. The variable index indicates different time points. Is there a way to make a separate scatterplot (x vs. y) for each individual, all displayed in the same output, and ordered based on a third variable (z)? If so, can color then be added to indicate degree of third variable (z)? Data below, Thanks.

```
> dput(dat1.1)
  structure(list(id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
  4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
  8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
  1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
  15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
  9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 
  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
  16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), x = c(7.443917, 7.520429, 7.446833, 
  8.07893, 8.534033, 8.263931, 7.598647, 6.902987, 7.672617, 7.739256, 
  7.591341, 8.101125, 7.811751, 6.596834, 6.637652, 8.467165, 7.835399, 
  6.500149, 7.083198, 7.531798, 6.110208, 6.368534, 5.26318, 6.735778, 
  5.580152, 5.460161, 5.844303, 6.258181, 7.191627, 5.105033, 6.760193, 
  5.857215, 5.866264, 6.769086, 6.547294, 5.623804, 4.675815, 6.153901, 
  6.040519, 6.236045, 8.216397, 6.097841, 5.491311, 5.831432, 6.297337, 
  6.655688, 5.553445, 6.37449, 6.271961, 6.959645, 7.080341, 6.46092, 
  6.476955, 7.221111, 6.219023, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8.21752, 7.589581, 
  8.363739, 8.849697, 7.78645, 7.494006, 7.827766, 9.11352, 7.80884, 
  6.701855, 6.259061, 5.523358, 6.186617, 6.548538, 6.6937, 7.213297, 
  5.243428, 7.510827, 7.054297, 7.603241), y = c(106L, 114L, 50L, 
  50L, 56L, 46L, 50L, 52L, 114L, 50L, 56L, 26L, 48L, 52L, 48L, 
  54L, 54L, 56L, 52L, 50L, 84L, 86L, 88L, 86L, 82L, 84L, 88L, 84L, 
  86L, 84L, 86L, 86L, 84L, 84L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 84L, 86L, 120L, 
  106L, 168L, 116L, 56L, 108L, 68L, 68L, 70L, 74L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
  72L, 70L, 118L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 60L, 62L, 52L, 90L, 50L, 
  50L, 54L, 56L, 52L, 30L, 78L, 30L, 52L, 54L, 52L, 80L, 86L, 46L, 
  54L, 84L), z = c(33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
  33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 54L, 54L, 
  54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 
  54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
  56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 50L, 
  50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 
  50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -80L))
```

Comment: What role does `index` play in the production of the plots?  What's the difference between the "order" of `z` and the "degree" of `z`?

Comment: These's also a 1-to-1 correspondence between `id` and `z` in your test data.

Comment: Index is not relevant to the plots other than to indicate the number of points in each plot. "Order" and "degree" of z refer to the same concept. The order of the individual scatterplots would be based on the degree of "z". Also, the dot color would be based on "z" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this come close to giving you what you want?

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(z=as.factor(z)) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y) {
      .x %>% 
        ggplot() +
          geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z)) +
          facet_wrap(vars(z)) +
          scale_colour_manual(drop=FALSE, values=d %>% distinct(z) %>% pull(z))  +
          labs(title=.x$id[1])
    },
    .keep=TRUE
  )
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Points to note:

- `group_map` applies a function to each group of a grouped data frame.  `.x` refers to the data in the current group, `.y` is a one row tibble defining the group.  `.keep` requests that the grouping variables are kept in `.x`.
- `drop=FALSE` in the call to `scale_colour_manual()` ensures that unused factor levels are retained in the legend (and hence different levels of `z` are distinguishable between plots).

Comment: This is precisely what I'm looking for. Is there a way to make each plot exactly the same range? For example, y axis range = 40:150 and x-axis range = 4.5:10, for all plots?

Comment: axes for facets within the same call will use the same scale by default.  But that's not visible here because you have only one facet per plot.  To make the axis ranges the same across groups (ie across `id`s) add a call to `coord_cartesian` to the pipe.  For example `... + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(40, 150), ylim=c(4.5, 10))`.  `coord_cartesian` is vastly superior to `lims`/`xlim`/`ylim`, IMHO, because it avoids unexpected results due to filtering when calculating summaries.  That's not an issue here, but it's never too early to learn good habits. :=)