# Create multiple plots in R based on column value but colour plots based on a second column

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I want to plot VarA by VarB in a line graph using ggplot2, but I want a separate plot for each unique ID value and colour the plots by VarC and change shape of the points by VarD.

I can create the individual plots using the following code:

```
plot_list <- lapply(split(data.df, data.df$ID), function(x)
    
{
  ggplot(x, aes(x=VarA, y=VarB)) + 
    geom_point()+
    theme_bw()
})
```

But would like to colour points based on another variable (VarC) and change the shape of the points based on a final variable (VarD).

Variables C and D are both factorial with 2 levels.

Comment: Add `colour=VarC, shape=VarD` or similar to your `aes()` call.

Comment: I have already tried this, and it does not work. All plots are returned with the same colour points.

Comment: I think it is because I am trying to colour by sex (male, female) and each ID has only one sex assigned to it so when I add colour = VarC to aes() the dataframe being used to make the plot has only one level.

Comment: In that case, add `drop=FALSE` to a relevant `scale_xxxx_manual` call, as I suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73718207/is-there-a-way-to-produce-multiple-x-y-scatterplots-at-once-based-on-grouping-va/73718829#73718829).  It's all in the online doc.

Answer (score 0):

ggplot contains aesthetics for colour and point shape, change the aesthetic call to:

```
aes(x=VarA,
    y=VarB,
    colour=varC,
    shape=varD)
```

The aesthtic fill is used instead of colour for some geoms, and shape will cause problems if included in geoms that don't use it but this should work for geom_point.

Add facet_wrap to the plot to separate graphs for each value of ID:

```
+facet_wrap(~ID)
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the function to create the plots as I have a dataframe containing over 10 million rows, and ID has 47 levels. The plots created using facet_wrap() are not clear enough to properly visualise the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
plot_list <- lapply(split(data.df.new, data.df.new$Sheep_ID), function(x)
  
{
  ggplot(x, aes(x=VarA, y=VarB, colour = VarC)) + 
    geom_point()+
    theme_bw() +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("R" = "blue", "E" = "pink")) + # Add in specific colour for each factor level. 
})
```